# How to remove decimal point if the number more than "10" in swift

Tags: ios, swift, decimal

How to remove decimal point value if the number is more than 10.0. Below is the code what i have tried. At below code i am getting the value and i put the condition that if value is less than 1km then show number in meter, if value is more than 1 then show the number in km and if the value is greater than 10.0 then i am not able to remove the decimal point

```
let resultDelivery = String(format: "%.1f", Obj.distance)// Here getting value from api either i get 0.5 or 6.5 or 11.5
            if (resultDelivery.starts(with: "0")){
                let resultDelivery2 = String(format: "%.f", Obj.distance/1 * 1000)
                cell.lblDeliverykm?.text = resultDelivery2.description + " " + "m".Localized() + "  " + "" // result is 900 m
            }
            else if (resultDelivery.starts(with: "10.0")){
                let resultDelivery2 = String(format: "%.0f", Obj.distance)
                cell.lblDeliverykm?.text = resultDelivery2.description + " " + "km".Localized() + "  " + "" // couldn’t able to remove decimal point 
            }
            else {
                cell.lblDeliverykm?.text = resultDelivery.description + " " + "km".Localized() + "  " + "" // result is 8.6 km
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah the joys of C-style formatting strings.

I present this as an alternative approach:

```swift
extension String.StringInterpolation
{
    public mutating func appendInterpolation<F: BinaryFloatingPoint>(distance: F)
    {
        if distance < 1 {
            appendLiteral("\(Int(distance * 1000))m")
        }
        else if distance >= 10 {
            appendLiteral("\(Int(distance))km")
        }
        else
        {
            let d = (distance * 10).rounded(.toNearestOrEven) / 10
            appendLiteral("\(d)km")
        }
    }
}


print("\(distance: 0.1)")
print("\(distance: 1)")
print("\(distance: 10)")
print("\(distance: 100)")
```

The output is

```sh
100m
1.0km
10km
100km
```

This will accept `Double`, `Float`, `Float80`, `Float16` and any other type conforming to `BinaryFloatingPoint`.

If you want localizable formats, look into `NumberFormatter`.

[EDIT] as noted by @flanker in comments, `LengthFormatter` with its method, `string(from: String, unit: LengthFormatter.Unit) -> String` would be the way to go rather than `NumberFormatter`

Comment: If you want to use the Formatter subclasses then you'd be better using the LengthFormatter, and the method `func string(fromValue value: Double, unit: LengthFormatter.Unit) -> String`

Comment: Good suggestion.  I just updated my answer to include it.

Comment: @ChipJarred how do i implement this in view controller ?

Comment: You can just assign it:  `cell.lblDeliverykm?.text = "\(distance: Obj.distance)".`

Comment: @MohammedNabil, just in case it's not clear, you don't implement the extension "in" the `ViewController`.  Extensions have to be defined in top-level code.  However, if you don't need to use this String interpolation anywhere else, you can put it in your `ViewController` file and make it `#fileprivate`.

Comment: This answer doesn't take negative numbers into account, not a big thing but it should be noted.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, That's true, though neither did the OP's code.  If it's used as truly "distance" and not relative position, then one should probably take the absolute value inside the string interpolation.